# Change cursor to wait cursor for entire application

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I made a tiny re-usable modal form that has a label (for a "Please wait" message) and a background worker.  (We'll call it WaitForm)
The form is meant to be re-usable within the application.

When "Load" fires, it will call the backgroundworker's DoWork event (which is delegated so that any code that calls on this form can do its own operation).

While it is running, I want all forms to display a wait cursor.  Because this form is modal, the wait cursor will only appear while the user is hovering over the WaitForm.  If you move your mouse and hover over the parent form instead, the cursor changes back to the default arrow.

I've tried the following, both individually and in combinations with others :

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
this.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

_Parent.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;  //I tried to pass the calling parent form as a parameter in the constructor of the "WaitForm" so that I can set its cursor.
```

The WaitForm works as intended.  It displays and launches the backgroundworker.  The only thing that makes me grind my teeth is the cursor.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: One way would be a `List<Form>` in a static class, each time you instantiate a Form add it to the list, then when you want to set each forms cursor you can iterate over the list. The thing is though, why even use Background Worker when you want a Modal, single threaded approach? Like the point of a background worker is to free up the app to let the user do other things on the main thread

Comment: That won't work unfortunately.  The problem is with the window being modal.  All cursors are set properly with Application.UseWaitCursor.  It seems it's just a windows behavior with modal forms.

Comment: And the point of using a background worker is to free up the UI, regardless of if you want a user to be able to do other things.  I don't want the rest of the UI to be frozen even if the user can't do anything with it.  It'd just look weird.

Comment: Whats the point of freeing up the UI if the cursor is a `WaitCursor`? Its completely misleading and un-intuitive.

Comment: The topic is wait cursors, not background workers.  Please stay on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a limitation that I believe is "By Design", you might want to resort to using a Win32 API to override the standard Winform behaviour.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetCursor(IntPtr hCursor);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);

private const uint OCR_NORMAL = 32512;

static Cursor ColoredCursor;
```

...

//========SET WINDOWS CURSOR========================================

```
    IntPtr cursor = LoadCursorFromFile("example.cur");
    bool ret_val = SetSystemCursor(cursor, OCR_NORMAL);
```

//========SET WINDOWS CURSOR========================================

//========SET FORM CURSOR========================================

```
    IntPtr cursor = LoadCursorFromFile("example.cur");
    ColoredCursor = new Cursor(cursor);
    this.Cursor = ColoredCursor;
```

//========SET FORM CURSOR========================================

//========SET FORM CURSOR FROM IMAGE==============================

```
    Bitmap hh = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("example.png");
    Graphics.FromImage(hh);
    IntPtr ptr = hh.GetHicon();
    Cursor c = new Cursor(ptr);
    this.Cursor = c;
```

//========SET FORM CURSOR FROM IMAGE==================================

Ref: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcursor

For additional examples see here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ea0bf74-760f-4f40-b64c-0cf7b0a56939/save-custom-cursor?forum=winforms

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.Image1;
      bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
      IntPtr hIcon = bmp.GetHicon();
      Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon);
      Cursor cur = new Cursor(hIcon);
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.cur", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        ico.Save(fs);
      cur.Dispose();
      ico.Dispose();
      DestroyIcon(hIcon);

      // Test it
      cur = new Cursor(@"c:\temp\test.cur");
      this.Cursor = cur;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for a waiting cursor in a user controller I use:

```
this.UseWaitCursor = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Four years later (now, 2022) the DllImport method feels a bit depricated and the second answer may be useful for an ASP controller, however it does not work for Net 4.7.2 and Winforms as asked.

Use **this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;** instead, in a Form method.

Restore the arrow cursor with  **this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;**